# Prediction IO engine build problem with sbt-launcher

Tags: predictionio

I'm trying to build an engine with pio-docker but it seems like the link for downloading sbt-launcher is broken so it can't be done

[image: sbt-launcher downloading error]

I did manually place the launcher in the `$HOME/.sbt/launchers/1.2.8/` but it doesn't work (the **.sbt** folder is placed in **$HOME** by default after installing it and it cannot be placed in root folder).

Can anyone suggest how to fix this?

Comment: did you find any answer ??